# Is there a difference between webhdfs:// and hdfs:// in terms of underlying protocol?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

Right now I am ingesting logs via HttpFS, which is falling apart at the sheer volume. I cannot run JVM on my edge for performance reasons. So I was thinking of using the native protocol for ingest (I've heard it's either IPC or raw network socket magic)

## webhdfs HttpFS underlying

hadoop fs -put localfile -fs webhdfs://datanode:14000/hadoopfile

## hdfs ?? what's underlying

hadoop fs -put localfile hdfs://namenode/hadoopfile

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, there is actually no difference as the underlying protocol in both the cases is TCP/IP.

Comment: I think he means REST (webhdfs://) vs RPC (hdfs://)

Comment: Oh..Perhaps..I was actually caught up by 'underlying'.

Comment: So there is a difference? One is HTTP, and the other binary?